# Drupal 7 change block subject in template.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks, drupal-templates, drupal-alter

I have a block in my page and that block has a title. How can i remove this title (subject) within template.php? I tried `hook_block_view_block_alter()` but it doesn't seem to work? I could add a space character in the block configuration screen but it doesn't look the right way for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the special token `<none>` in the block configuration screen as the title, that will make it blank for page output.